# expo auth azure ad exchange token

Tags: azure-active-directory, expo, expo-auth-session

Ran on ios in expo go.
Authorization token works correctly but then cannot redeem. Gives me the error below, I looked but the solution to this error is an to put an origin header, which isn't possible in ios.

More info: AADSTS9002327: Tokens issued for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type may only beredeemed via cross-origin requests.

```
const discovery = AuthSession.useAutoDiscovery('https://login.microsoftonline.com/' + tenantId +'/v2.0');

const redirectUri = AuthSession.makeRedirectUri({scheme: "{my scheme}", path: 'auth'});

  // Request
  const [request, result, promptAsync] = AuthSession.useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId,
      scopes: ["User.Read"],
      redirectUri,
      prompt: AuthSession.Prompt.SelectAccount
    },
    discovery,
  );

async function getAuthToken() {
  promptAsync().then(async (codeResponse) => {
      if (request && codeResponse?.type === 'success' && discovery) {
        AuthSession.exchangeCodeAsync(
          {
            clientId,
            code: codeResponse.params.code,
            extraParams: request.codeVerifier
              ? { code_verifier: request.codeVerifier }
              :undefined,
            redirectUri,
            scopes: request.scopes
          },
          discovery,
        ).then((response) => {
          //Success
        }).catch(e => {console.log(e)});
      }
    });
}
```

I have tried getting the token like in the repo https://github.com/pinecat/azure-ad-graph-expo